# How to enable multiple options selection in headless-ui combobox/autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, combobox, autocomplete, headless-ui

I am using headless-UI combobox/autocomplete.I would like to enable multiple options selections with this component. Can anyone tell me, how can we achieve  this?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `multiple` prop word. An array will be passed to value instead of a single option:

```
<Combobox value={selectedPeople} multiple>
```

Link: https://headlessui.com/react/combobox#selecting-multiple-values

Comment: Do you know how to style individual value in displayValue under Combobox.Input?

Comment: What value do you mean? Can you give an example of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @Tajs you might look at this [chapter](https://headlessui.com/react/combobox#selecting-multiple-values) and search for displayValue